# How to make this SpringML (or other) Spark SFTP Server connector work?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sftp, databricks

I am trying to build a Spark Job which can connect to a SFTP Server and drop a csv file there. The option that I found was to use the [SpringML](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp) package. However, I keep getting a `noSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;`. This was once described in an [issue](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp/issues/46) related to the package.

It is not exactly clear to me how the issue was resolved and if I am just making a user error. I use the newest version of the SpringML package [(1.0.3)](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.springml/sftp.client/1.0.3/jar) on Databricks and installed it through the Databricks Maven in "Create Library".

The code I use looks as follows:

```
// Read sample dataframe from table
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM default.some_test_data")

// Write sample data to a SFTP server
df.write.format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
           option("host", "SFTP_HOST").
           option("username", "SFTP_USER").
           option("password", "password").
           option("fileType", "fileType")
          .save(/some_test_data.csv)
```

I am happy with any working example, even if it is using another open source package. Also feel free to point out what I miss?

Note: My Spark Version is 3.1.2, Scala 2.12

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for Spark 3.0 & Scala 2.12 yet.

Comment: Yeah in the end I realized and we went with an implementation of SFTP connection via Redsocks.

Comment: Would you mind sharing steps you followed to integrate Spark & Redsocks?